# How to compress video and send it to firebase storage like whatsapp in react native

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

i have to dev an app who can send video to firebase storage the goal is to be able to send video fast like whatsapp for exemple. My problem is that some video are heavy and take time to be send so i would like to compress video. For that i use
ffmpeg-kit but the compression take so much time i have a video of 1 min for exemple.So i would like to know how's better to proceed to compress video fast and send it to database ? Is it possible to devide the video in small part and parallelize ffmpeg task and then build the video again ? Don't know if someone have something to help could be nice cause i'm lost. Ty and here's my compress code:

```js
 function processVideo(videoUrl) {
    const finalVideo = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/audioVideoFinal.mp4`;
    const destPath = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/test.mp4`;
    RNFS.copyFile(videoUrl, destPath).then(()=>{
      const str_cmd = `-i ${destPath} -vf scale=-2:960 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -r 30 ${finalVideo}`
      FFmpegKit.executeAsync(str_cmd, async (session) => {
        const returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
            const path =Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + finalVideo : finalVideo
            setUrlCompress(path);
            RNFS.unlink(destPath);
        } else {
            //console.log(`Encode failed with state ${state} and rc ${returnCode}.${notNull(failStackTrace, "\\n")}`);
        }
      }, log => {}, statistics => {}).then(session => console.log(`Async FFmpeg process started with sessionId ${session.getSessionId()}.`));
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-video-helper](https://github.com/classapp/react-native-video-helper) package for compressing your video. This is what I come up with when I was also stuck.

You can use that like:

```js
import RNVideoHelper from 'react-native-video-helper';

const sourceUri = 'assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=0F3F0000-9518-4F32-B389-7117F4C2B069&ext=mov';

RNVideoHelper.compress(sourceUri, {
    startTime: 10, // optional, in seconds, defaults to 0
    endTime: 100, //  optional, in seconds, defaults to video duration
    quality: 'low', // default low, can be medium or high
    defaultOrientation: 0 // By default is 0, some devices not save this property in metadata. Can be between 0 - 360
}).progress(value => {
    console.warn('progress', value); // Int with progress value from 0 to 1
}).then(compressedUri => {
    console.warn('compressedUri', compressedUri); // String with path to temporary compressed video
});
```

Hope this works for you.